# LATERAL VIEW and CASE Statement in KSQL

Tags: view, case, ksqldb, lateral

is there a LATERAL VIEW Statement in KSQL i cant finde anything in the docs. Or is there any alternative Comand to get the same result on column? When I use the Statement I get following error

```
line 1:64: mismatched input 'view' expecting ';'
Caused by: org.antlr.v4.runtime.InputMismatchException
```

Also as i see there is no CASE Statement, is there also some alternative for this?

Answer (score 0):

These are not currently supported. You can upvote the relevant github issues to help us gauge relative demand for the features:

- [CASE](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/620)
- [EXPLODE / LATERAL VIEW](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/527)